# OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCSprite draw] 530 to run project on divice in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am running my cocos2d program on simulator. It works fine but when I run it on device, it throws error  OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCSprite draw] 530 and [CCGLView swapBuffers] 283. In my program I want to push one scene to another scene.At that time it shows error and black screen of the next scene.Please help me about it. I also tried to google it.

Note : My apps is not crash but problem to draw sprite.

My Code As below:

First Load LoadingLayer as below.

```
-(void) directorDidReshapeProjection:(CCDirector*)director
{

        if ([[director runningScene] isRunning])
        {

            [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]];
        }
        else
        {
            [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[LoadingLayer scene]];
        }

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    // Create the main window
    window_ = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


    glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                                   depthFormat:0
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];

    director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    director_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    // Display FSP and SPF
    [director_ setDisplayStats:NO];

    // set FPS at 60
    [director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

    // attach the openglView to the director
    [director_ setView:glView];

    // 2D projection
    [director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];

    //  [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection3D];

    // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
    if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

    // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
    // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
    // You can change this setting at any time.
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

        CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
    [sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];             // Default: NO. No fallback suffixes are going to be used
    [sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];      // Default on iPhone RetinaDisplay is "-hd"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];                   // Default on iPad is "ipad"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];    // Default on iPad RetinaDisplay is "-ipadhd"

    // Assume that PVR images have premultiplied alpha
    [CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];

    // Create a Navigation Controller with the Director
    navController_ = [[MyNavigationController alloc]    initWithRootViewController:director_];
    navController_.navigationBarHidden = YES;


    // for rotation and other messages
    [director_ setDelegate:navController_];

    // set the Navigation Controller as the root view controller
    [window_ setRootViewController:navController_];

    // make main window visible
    [window_ makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

After LoadingLayer it push to viewcontroller.it has button click on it go to HelloWorldLayer.

```
-(void)Button
{
        director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];
        [director_ replaceScene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:director_ animated:YES];
}
```

flow as scene to viewcontroller to scene.

app is not crash but it got error as below

[image]

on Simulator it run good but CPU uses reach 95% to 100%.

[image]

Comment: If you wrote any custom OpenGL code please post that. Without any code this question can not be answered. For definition of OpenGL error codes see: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Error

Comment: i am simply push viewcontroller to scene as above . i am  not uses custom OpenGL code.

Comment: LearnCocos2D it may be problem of CPU uses. how can i solve it.

Comment: No, it's definitely an OpenGL problem. As the link posted above shows, the error (0x506) is "Invalid Framebuffer Operation". Since it works on the simulator, I'm guessing that Cocos2D is trying to do something like create a new FBO and for some reason it's failing on the actual device. I don't know Cocos2D at all, so I have no idea how you'd debug that, especially since you aren't the one creating the Framebuffer. Good luck!

Comment: definitely an OpenGL problem its ok but it run well on simulator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a cocos2d application and not a UIKit hybrid right? In that case why are you calling pushViewController when you are simply just switching the scene (CCScene)? Try removing:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:director_ animated:YES];
```

There is no reason you should be pushing the director, it is already present. When you are switching CCScene's you are not creating a new view controller.

Comment: I know it present scene.but afer that scene i go to viewcontroller and after i want to go viewcontroller to scene.so i want to push of particular scene

Comment: Oh ok so you are switching to another UIKit-based view controller then switching back to the previous one with the cocos2d director? One thing you can try is to end the director before you switch away from it, then restart it once you go back. The director has an end method, but in order to restart it you'd have to do all of the code in the app delegate that setup cocos2d. You can move that code into a separate method so that you can call it whenever you need to.

Answer (score 0):

> but afer that scene i go to viewcontroller

If you want to use UIKit and Cocos2d for iPhone at the same time, I highly recommend you to read attachDemo to achieve the goal.

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/tree/master-v2/tests/attachDemo